# postgresql10 jdbc parallel queries

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-10

I have watched that my queries never executed in parallel by the PostgreSQL server. If I execute the same query by pgAdmin, Heidi etc., it is executed by the specified number of parallel worker processes.
But there seems to be no jdbc parameter to enable or disable this behavior.
Does anybody know a solution for that?

As an example I use 3 tables: file, gps and cell(info). The query I use forces Postgres to use sequential scans - and one of them is parallel.

```
select lon,lat,level
  from t_qd_state_cell tc
  join t_qd_state_gps  tp on tp.id_state=tc.id_state
  join t_qb_file tf on tf.id = tc.id_file
 where lon is not null
   and level is not null
   and tf.id>6000000
```

The corresponding query plan can be found here:

[image: query plan image]

If starting from pgAdmin the parallel execution can be watched using server status or htop. But from Java programs there is only one process.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is the use of PreparedStatements with parameters which might yield different execution plan compared to a query with constant values. But that sounds unlikely too

Comment: Post the execution plans for both cases (you can use `auto_explain` to get the JDBC execution plan).

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to `preferQueryMode` parameter of PostgreSQL JDBC driver. The default value is `extended` which exhibits this behavior. Values `simple` and  `extendedForPrepared` work as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work - but not really! Using `simple` I can see the parallel execution, but the result is readable. And using one of the extended versions it will be executed only by one thread/process.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "but the results is readable", could you please explain in more detail? One more thing is, that if you are reading the results via cursor i.e. using fetchSize(n) for n > 0 then you won't be able to use parallel workers under any condition. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html.

Comment: Ooops. I mean the result is **not** readable. I use standard JDBC functions: open the connection, create a prepared statement, execute the query and iterate through the result set. But the result set was not as expected.